# Java: array transfers between classes but values do not?

Tags: java, class, arraylist, null

In the following Java code I am populating an ArrayList in one class then using the ArrayList in another class. However, the array transfers but is filled with null values. I have debugged the code and the ArrayList does get populated but its values do not transfer.

**First Class:**

```
public String[] log = new String[100];
public ArrayList llog= new ArrayList();
int arraypos= 0;
public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
  if (e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
    GlobalScreen.unregisterNativeHook();
  }
  System.out.println(" " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()).toLowerCase() + " ");
  llog.add(NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()).toString().toLowerCase());
  System.out.println("list:" + llog.get(arraypos));
  arraypos = arraypos + 1;  
}

public ArrayList getStrokes (){
  return this.llog;
}
```

**Second Class:**

```
public void TeslaTimer()
{
  int delay = 10000; //1 sec = 1000 
  int period = 90000; // repeat every sec.

  Timer timer = new Timer();
  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
  {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
      GlobalKeyListener keyl = new GlobalKeyListener();
      ArrayList keylog=keyl.getStrokes();

      //TeslaLogger savetoFile = new TeslaLogger();
      //savetoFile.TeslaLogger(keylog);
      System.out.println("Ring Ring");
      for(int i =0; i < keylog.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(keylog.get(i));
      }
    }
  }, delay, period);
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Do you get an error? And code formatting is pretty unreadable..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instance of `GlobalKeyListener` in `TeslaTimer` is not the same instance as the one you are adding to - the are different objects each with their own list.

You must make the same instance of `GlobalKeyListener` available to your `run()` method, or perhaps use a `static` variable (which is like a global variable).

---

Here's the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) in action that you could use to make it work:

```
public class GlobalKeyListener {

    // rest of class omitted
    private static GlobalKeyListener INSTANCE = new GlobalKeyListener();

    public static GlobalKeyListener getInstance() { 
        return INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

then wherever you need to use it locally:

```
GlobalKeyListener globalKeyListener = GlobalKeyListener.getInstance();
globalKeyListener.getStrokes(); // etc
```

All code will then be using the *same* instance.

Comment: how can i make the same instance available to my run() method?

Answer (score 1):

You create a new GlobalKeyListener, and that makes an instance of the class GlobalKeyListener.  This instance of the class will run the line: public ArrayList llog= new ArrayList(); (thus creating a new array list with no elements).  You then try to get the array list keylog=keyl.getStrokes(), and the empty array list is given.  If you want the array list to persist between instantiations of the class try making the llog array list static.  This will make it so that all instances of your first class share the llog array.  Does this make sense?